# Round up numbers in gvisTable

Tags: shiny

I am new to googleVis and I simply cannot get it to round up my numbers in my table to upto 2 places of decimal. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Currently I am using the code

```
gvisTable(round(data_frame),2)
```

I have tried

```
gvisTable(data_frame, formats=list(data_frame="##.##"))
```

but has not helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify the column that you want to round. In my example below I round the 'Revenue' column. You can look into formats [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/googleVis/docs/gvisTable) and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis_examples.html)

My example below:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

# Sample data
dat <- data.frame(Product=c("Milk", "Butter", "Yoghurt", "Total"),Revenue=c(2230.32787, 43908.123432, 231.5343, 46369.1112))

ui = fluidPage(htmlOutput("my_table"))
server = function(input, output) {
  output$my_table <- renderGvis({gvisTable(dat, options=list(width=300, height=150),formats=list('Revenue'='##.##'))})}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: anyway we could use column numbers instead of column names? what if  too many columns need the same format?